# Vertex-independent paths

Tags: graphs, sets, equality

Let $s$ and $t$ be 2 vertices (not adjacent) in graph $G$. 
Let $p_l(s,t;G)$ be the $maximum$ number of vertex-independent paths from $s$ to $t$ in graph $G$, of length $\le$ $l$ ($l \in \{1,...,|G|\}$). Also, let $k_l(s,t;G)$ be the $minimum$ cardinal of a set of vertices (different from $s$ and $t$), that if we remove from the graph there won't be any more paths from $s$ to $t$ of length $\le$ $l$.

I) Please prove that $p_l(s,t;G) \le k_l(s,t;G)$ $(*)$
II) Using the below graph prove that the $(*)$ inequality is strict.
[image]

III) Find values for $l \in \{2,...|G|\}$ so that $p_l(s,t;G) = k_l(s,t;G)$ for any graph $G$ and vertices $s$ and $t$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello! We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted. You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/), or use the search engine of this site to find similar questions that were already answered.

Comment: I already answered this: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/49925/disjoint-paths-of-length-at-most-l-and-the-number-of-nodes-to-remove-to-vanish-t/49937#49937.